# Pure Virtual function override

Tags: c++

Ok so I have a bit of a silly question but I think it might be useful if there was a way to do it.

Anyway, assume I have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        virtual void Show() = 0;
};
```

What if I want to use Foo without inherriting? Is there a way to simply do the following (rather than create a whole new class to implement Show):

```
Foo F;
F.Show = [&]{/*Do something here*/}; //Assign some function or Lambda to Foo instance F
```

Is there a way to do that? I know it seems silly but I just have to know if that or something similar can be done.

It obviously doesn't compile :l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do that?

No, you can't instantiate `Foo` if it has a pure virtual member function.

> I just have to know if that or something similar can be done.

It depends what you mean by similar. If you forget about the pure virtual, you can give `Foo::Show()` an implementation in terms of, say, an `std::function<void()>`, which you can set from a lambda expression, another `std::function<void()>` or any callable entity with that signature and return type.

```
#include <functional>
class Foo
{
 public:
  virtual void Show() { fun(); }
  std::function<void()> fun;
};
```

Then

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.fun = []{std::cout << "Hello, World!";};
  f.Show();
}
```

**Note** as suggested in @MrUniverse's comment, you should check whether the function has been assinged before calling it. This can be easily done:

```
virtual void Show() { if (fun) fun(); };
```

Comment: Ahh I like this. I'll use this instead :)

Comment: Don't forget to check if 'fun' is assigned to before blindly calling it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like that can work :

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  std::function<void(void)> Show;
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;

  f.Show = [&] () { std::cout << "Hello !" << std::endl; };
  f.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure virtual classes can not be instantiated at all

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is a local anonymous class:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo
{
    public:
        virtual void Show() = 0;
};
int main() {
    struct : Foo {
        void Show() {
            std::cout << "Hello world\n";
        }
    } f;
    f.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can instead store a function pointer called show in the class.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        void (*Show)();
        Foo()
        {
            Show = 0;
        }
}
```

Then if Show != 0 you can call it (aka if the user assigns a function pointer to it).